# C++ user-defined string literal template weird issue (getting string literal length as compile-time constant)

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++20, user-defined-literals

I'm trying to define a user-defined string literal template.

Shouldn't that code snippet work? / Why doesn't it work?

```cpp
template<char...>
constexpr
int operator ""_x () {
    return 0;
}

int x = "abc"_x;
```

The operator declaration is 'accepted' by the compiler as valid - C++ is so strict on the user-defined literals that any deviation from the spec'ed declarations is diagnosed as error. Therefore the acceptence of that declaration suggests to me that it is fine - as I would expect - but none of the compilers I've tried (GCC, Clang, MSVC - all *trunk*s on godbolt.org) compile the next definition which uses the operator, of which Clang and MSVC can't find matching literal operator, and GCC gives an amazingly weird error (you can see it full at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/qjfr17Y8b)), of which the part:

```
(...)
<source>:7:9: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<char ...<anonymous> > constexpr int operator""_x()'
    7 | int x = "abc"_x;
      |         ^~~~~~~
<source>:7:9: note:   expected a constant of type 'char', got 'char'
```

(compiler speaking) I expected `char`, but I got `char`... Maaan... I don't know what to do now! - is the most confusing...

I'm using Clang 15 for this project, so if there is a compiler specific fix for this, I would be grateful for that one.

EDIT: Based on the first answer - I must add that this is a *minimal* snippet showing the issue and is not the target use-case of that function - it being a template is critical - to be more specific:
I want to implement multi-character literal operator, but unfortunately someone defining the C++ spec decided to forbid the `int16`/`int32` type to be accepted as user-defined literal argument, which are the underlying types of Clang's 'ab'/'abc'/'abcd', which I decided to solve by using the string literal ("") instead of character one (''), but for that to work I need to restrict the acceptable length of the source string literals at compile-time, which (as far as my knowledge goes) is only possible in C++ if the literal is passed as template parameter.

Comment: Gcc has extension for template C-string user literal: `template <typename Char, Char...Cs> MyType operator""_udl();` (`"foo_bar"_udl`).

Comment: It sounds like that's what it's trying to interpret it as (`_x<char, 'a', 'b', 'c'>`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a template in that case.

```c++
#include <string>

constexpr int operator""_x (const char* str, std::size_t) {
  return 0;
}

int x = "abc"_x;
```

Templates are used for converting literals other than string literals:

```
template<char...>
constexpr
int operator ""_x () {
    return 0;
}

int x = 10_x;
```

With the new information in the question, limiting the acceptable string literal length:

```
#include <string>
 
template<std::size_t N>
struct StringLiteral {
  char s[N]{};
  constexpr StringLiteral(char const(&p)[N]) {
    // restrict the acceptable length with 4 chars + terminator
    static_assert(N <= 5);
    std::copy(p, p + N, s);
  }
};
 
template<StringLiteral L>
constexpr int operator""_x() {
  // Use L.s
  return 0;
}
 
int x = "abc"_x;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nvj1GGjbM

Or make the struct the string literal length independent:

```
#include <string>
 
template<std::size_t N>
struct StringLiteral {
  char s[N]{};
  std::size_t n{};
  constexpr StringLiteral(char const(&p)[N]) : n(N) {
    std::copy(p, p + N, s);
  }
};
 
template<StringLiteral L>
constexpr int operator""_x() {
  // restrict the acceptable length with 4 chars + terminator
  static_assert(L.n <= 5);
  // Use L.s
  return 0;
}

int x = "abc"_x;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hdP4aoefn

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work for my use-case I added more context in the question.

Comment: Ok.... I see that idea now... I did not understand that from C++ docs (sadly) - I'll give you one up, but I still hope on someone's idea how to solve mine issue - EDIT: I cannot give you one up... sorry... (what an annoying website....)

Comment: That works, thanks! But an important difference from the GCC extension proposed in comments below the question, is that here the terminating-null counts to the literal length, while there it does not - which makes me wonder whether someone could by accident pass a 5-letter (for ex.) string WITHOUT a terminating-null, potentially causing weird bug... but that solution is at least more portable. I have not even considered it earlier, as I assumed the restrictive types of user-defined literal operators would prevent that... I can upvote now for some reason, btw...

Comment: `static constexpr char not_nul_terminated[1] = {'a'}; operator""_x<StringLiteral(not_nul_terminated)>();` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fGWzqEcjK) ;-)

Comment: Even shorter: `operator""_x<(char[]) { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' }>()` ;) - @Jarod42 - but that's still pretty deliberate...